# str_to_date not working in my query MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, date, formatting

```
select * ,str_to_date(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
from numberofmortageloans;
```

[Screenshot of the code not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roGLT.jpg)
[image]

I'm sure I am missing something but let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your date values are invalid, like '2005-03-00'.

If STR_TO_DATE() can't evaluate the date as a legitimate date, it returns NULL.

```
mysql> select str_to_date('2005-03-00', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2005-03-00', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------+
| NULL                                  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

If you try it with a real date, STR_TO_DATE() works fine.

```
mysql> select str_to_date('2005-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2005-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2005-03-01                            |
+---------------------------------------+
```

So, garbage in, garbage out.

The manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) says in part:

> If the NO_ZERO_DATE or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed. In that case, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and generates a warning:

```
mysql> set sql_mode='';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select str_to_date('2005-03-00', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2005-03-00', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2005-03-00                            |
+---------------------------------------+
```

So you could change your SQL_MODE. But I would recommend you fix your data instead.